# Dynamically insert special character into document title

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, document

I am trying to update the document.title with Javascript. This works fine, but now I want to insert the ü character into the title, which gives me a question mark at the place where the ü is supposed to be.

Here is my code (I omitted the rest of the title for clarity):

```
document.title = '\u2019 - \u252';
```

The strange thing is that the \u2019 part does work and gives me a quote, as expected. My charset is UTF-8, by the way.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Since the document title is displayed outside the window (ie, on the title bar or the tab), what's probably relevant is the current locale and character set of the system where the browser is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want `document.title = '\u00FC';` ? the &# and \u numbers are different in many places, or so i've found in my usages.

Comment: @Evert: FYI, using the [Unicode Code Converter](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/) you can easily convert those values yourself.

Answer (score 1):

What's \u252? It doesn't seem to be a valid unicode escape, try \u0252?

Comment: I tried \u252 because I thought of &#252;.
\u0252 gives me a ɒ character, which doesn't seem right either..

Answer (score 0):

Update: Apologies. I read it wrong. Thought you were looking for "ɒ" which is the result I get...

This worked for me on Chrome, Firefox and Safari (OSX)

```
document.title = '\u0252';
```